# org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Reader record field type:UNION pos:1 matches multiple fields in writer record schema

Tags: java, avro

I've been recently trying to compare two Avro Schemas using the SchemaCompatibility.[checkReaderWriterCompatibility](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/api/java/org/apache/avro/SchemaCompatibility.html) method and I'm being returned with the following exception, which I cannot understand. Yes I do understand the meaning of the exception, but I'm not sure why is it happening.

> org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Reader record field offerUid
> type:UNION pos:1 matches multiple fields in writer record schema

When I compare the [schemas](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/api/java/org/apache/avro/Schema.html), there's a column named `offerUid` in both without any differences. The only difference I see in the schema, which is expected, since I added a new description for a column. But the exception that throws is nothing related to the description that I updated.

This is the piece of line where it throws the exception:

```
SchemaCompatibility.SchemaPairCompatibility backwardsCompatibility = SchemaCompatibility.checkReaderWriterCompatibility(newSchema, existingSchema);
```

Has anyone faced the same? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: no such issue in my repo, paste more details on the description, such as avro version, jdk version, two compared schema...